# Graphs and Charts from Excel

Tags: java, android, excel, graph, ios4

I want to display graphs and charts generated from an Excel spreadsheet, on my Android device.  As far as I can see, my choices are:

1. Export the number data from Excel, and graph it on the device using a package like AChartEngine.
2. Export XML data from Excel, and graph it on the PC (using some other graphing package?) or graph it on the device (using some other graphing package?)
3. Create the graphic interactively on a PC using Excel, and take a screen snaphot.  Send that file to the device for display in an ImageView
4. arrange for the data to be a page on a web server, rather than in an Excel spreadsheet file.  Read from the page from the server and graph on the device, as in step 1.

Are there other alternatives to consider?

Are there any approaches which could be shared on other platforms, too, like for iOS and RIM

Thanks for any suggestions - it seems like this should be a solved problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically, or if there is an application available that already does this?

Comment: I'd like to get pointers to both alternatives, if they exist.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also use the google chart api to do it.

Comment: More info on Google charts API here:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery  It's an HTML-based solution, so need to display in a WebView, not a Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into this a couple months back, and I found AChartEngine to be the easiest library to work with. Some benefits are it is open-source, it has a nice community, and it is actively maintained. It's free too, which is great considering that some native libraries such as [Java Charts for Android](http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android) cost something like $140! I definitely wouldn't suggest using Excel to generate and display an `ImageView`... definitely go with a native library if anything. (Some libraries such as AChartEngine allow you to dynamically resize/reposition the chart on the screen, which might be a nice option to have later on).

Other than AChartEngine, some other libraries you might consider:

1. [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots)
2. [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home)